# Clicking this button in C# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

How do I click this specific button in selenium in C#

I tried the a tag but it doesn't work

```
<a class="btn-primary" href="http://myjunkyard.co.za/confirm" itemprop="url" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 16px; color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; line-height: 2em; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; border-radius: 30px; background-color: #201D19; margin: 0; padding: 5px 30px;" target="_blank">Confirm email address</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try locating this element with this XPath:

```cs
"//a[contains(@href,'http://myjunkyard.co.za/confirm')]"
```

Or this

```cs
"//a[text()='Confirm email address']"
```